# properly rewrite url configuration for wordpress blog inside larvavel project

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, laravel

On the web root I've all the folder of laravel and a folder blog containing a wordpress project.

[image: folder structure]

I would like to access to www.mywebsite.de/public/index.php url without specifying public/index.php.

To be more specific I'm using wordpress only as backoffice, so it would be ideal rewrite 
www.mywebsite.de/wp-admin in www.mywebsite.it/blog/wp-admin/

Thanks in advance for help.

==============================

I deleted .htaccess file containing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public
RewriteRule (.*) /public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Because all assets folder/subfolder/files under public folder become unreachable.

-mywebsite.ext become mywebsite.ext/public/index.php OK

-mywebsite.ext/myroute become mywebsite.ext/public/index.php/myroute OK

-mywebsite.ext/images/funnyimage.jpg become mywebsite.ext/public/index.php/images/funnyimage.jpg NOT OK it should be mywebsite.ext/public/images/funnyimage.jpg

I cannot make an excetpion for each folder and subfolder to distinguish them from a route.

Comment: Why don't you place your Wordpress `blog` directory in laravel `public` folder? This will work without any problem.

Comment: in public folder i apply recursively 777 permission, I don't think it's a good idea to do the same to the blog folder

Comment: Moving the `blog` directory won't automatically apply 777 permission to itself.

Comment: but I might have to use chmod later on public folder

Comment: edited because rewrite url for public/index.php work only before i clean browser cache...

Comment: Your main problem resides in that 777 permission approach.

Comment: Ok, currently someone can help me with first problem? 
"I would like to access to www.mywebsite.de/public/index.php url without specifying public/index.php."

Comment: @longy Then provide us your current .htaccess contents.

Comment: I have not .htaccess, take a look at updated question